# SystemJS loads many files for rxjs

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, systemjs, rxjs5

I have the following `systemjs.config.js` (based on some example I found on the internet):

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'js:': 'js/',
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'js:angular2/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'js:angular2/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'js:angular2/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'js:angular2/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'js:angular2/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'js:angular2/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'js:angular2/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'js:angular2/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'js:angular2/upgrade.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'js:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'js:in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

When I start my Angular2 application many individual rxjs files are loaded which takes a long time. I have a bundled version of RxJs in `js/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js`, so I tried to modify `systemjs.config.js` like this:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'js:': 'js/',
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'js:angular2/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'js:angular2/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'js:angular2/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'js:angular2/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'js:angular2/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'js:angular2/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'js:angular2/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'js:angular2/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'js:angular2/upgrade.umd.js',
            // other libraries
            'rxjs': 'js:rxjs/bundles/Rx.js',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'js:in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

When I try to start my application now, I get the following error in the browser:

```
Error: (SystemJS) Syntax error
    SyntaxError: Syntax error
       at Anonymous function (eval code:2:1)
    Evaluating http://localhost:37191/js/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js/Subject
    Evaluating http://localhost:37191/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:37191/app/main.js
```

My `main.ts` looks like this:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

And my `app.module.ts` looks like this:

```
import 'rxjs';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DeviceGroupsViewComponent } from './device-groups-view.component';

import { DeviceGroupService } from './devicegroup.service';
import { SourceTypeService } from './sourcetype.service';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        AppRoutingModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        DeviceGroupsViewComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DeviceGroupService,
        SourceTypeService
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

What do I have to change to make my app work with the bundled Rx.js?

Comment: Did you find best solution?

Answer (score 4):

if your setup is based on angular2 quickstart then you are doing OK.

However, you MUST NEVER

```
import {something} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

this is wrong and will import the entire RxJS library (when you only want to use Observable).

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

this is correct

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

and will reduce the number of imports. Ensure you app has no references to 'rxjs/Rx'

PS You don't want to pull in the entire RxJS library in a single file as it would be very big. That's the whole reason behind only importing the RxJS modules you need.

Comment: Making the mentioned change did actually reduce the number of rxjs libraries that was being loaded. But why is that the behavior and why is this not mentioned anywhere?

Answer (score 2):

Some time ago I made this demo that uses Angular2 and loads RxJS as a single bundle.

Basically, all I did was:

```
paths: {
    'rxjs*': 'https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12/dist/global/Rx.js'
},
```

where the only important thing is `rxjs*` that matches for example `rxjs/Subject` or `rxjs/add/operator/concat` and so on.

See live demo on plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/rnO74mQNuPsHAmrIVJ8j?p=preview

Comment: Wildcards in paths [will not be supported](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039) in the next major SystemJS release  - 0.20, so it looks like the only way to load Rx.js bundle will be via script tag, as it was done in earlier angular2 RC examples.

Comment: @artem That's interesting I didn't know that! It looks like it'll work the same way just without `*` as seen in this comment https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039#issuecomment-251283268

Comment: From my experience, without wildcards it could be made to work only if both key and value for path entry end with `/`