# How to load rxjs as one file in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

I have Angular 2 app.

**systemjs.config.js:**

```
 System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': "libs/"
        },
        map: {
            'rxjs': "npm:rxjs"
        }
    });
```

**Component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
    selector: 'test',
    templateUrl: './app/test.component.html'
})
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(...) { }

    ngOnInit() { ... }
}
```

And gulp copy to "libs" folder all js files from "*node_modules/rxjs*".

I see in browser console for about 100 requests from **rxjs** *(merge.js, fromEvent.js, toPromise.js, ...)*

If I change systemjs.config.js on:

```
'rxjs': "npm:rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"
```

I see errors, like that:

```
localhost/libs/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js/operator/toPromise.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Does it help me to improve performance if I will use only **node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js**?

And what should I do to use that single file?

Comment: Maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780363/systemjs-loads-many-files-for-rxjs/40788204#40788204

Comment: Also this https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039 but it depends on what version of SystemJS you're using.

Comment: I have error "Cannot read property 'call' of undefined (router.umd.min.js:8)". And what if I want to use local js file Rx.min.js instead cdn?

Answer (score 0):

This SystemJS config should be working when using RxJS in your project.

```
System.config({
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  packages: {
    '.': {
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    'vendor': {
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }
  }
});

System.config({
  map: {
    'main': 'main.js',

    /* ... */

    // Rxjs mapping
    'rxjs': 'https://unpkg.com/rxjs',
  },
  packages: {
  // Thirdparty barrels.
    'rxjs': {
      main: 'index'
    },
  }
});
```

Comment: And what if I want to use local downloaded package "rxjs", not cdn?