# Use single RxJs min file instead of rxjs folder

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

Angular 2 SystemJS config seems to look for a folder when it comes the RxJS. How can I make it to use `Rx.min.js`? I couldn't figure it out no matter what I tried as `'rxjs'` value in my config:

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'Scripts/Lib/Angular/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'Application',

            '@angular/core': 'npm:core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:forms.umd.js',

            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './Startup.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

Comment: what is the issue with that, if folder contains `index.js` which is exporting all the modules of rx then there is no need to use extensions.

Comment: The question probably needs the example that replicates the problem (a plunk).

Comment: @Jai This is a known problem, RxJS package files are retrieved one by one instead of one UMD bundle in Angular2+SystemJS setup.

Comment: @estus: So this is not possible? Do you have a Github link for the issue?

Comment: You can use wildcard `*` in `paths` option. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314480/how-to-import-observable-from-rx-not-angular/42341348#42341348 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780363/systemjs-loads-many-files-for-rxjs/40788204#40788204

Comment: @martin Indeed, it looks like it works for official A2 plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/nApK0DKOTqy9eC86jZSC?p=preview

Comment: @dstr Looks like it is possible in the end.

Comment: @estus Just note that this works only in SystemJS 0.19.* that's used by Angular2. If you waned to use the newer SystemJS 0.20.* than it won't work. https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039#issuecomment-251283268 and https://github.com/mgechev/angular-seed/issues/1785#issuecomment-276151482

Comment: @estus: Plunker is working, thanks. Can you post an answer so I can mark it as answer.