# Why do i get too many rxjs file calls in my angular 2 project? (seems to be all of them)

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs

> **EDIT:** i have another project thats also not packaged up, and has calls for observable,subscription,subscriver (and BehaviorSubject).
>   this project however uses those three but not BehaviorSubject.
>
> in the other project it makes 63 rxjs calls, and in this project it makes 340
>   rxjs calls
>
> I'm asking where to look for what is making those calls (both projects
>   are same in their..settings... both using systemjs,bot run in JIT
>   compilation (for now)

im using Observables, subscription etc in my project,
and everytime i import i import them specifically

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

also no lines that are like

```
import "rxjs/Rx";
```

anywhere in the project, but still, when the project starts, it calls for 340 files

[image]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42314480/how-to-import-observable-from-rx-not-angular/42341348#42341348 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40780363/systemjs-loads-many-files-for-rxjs/40788204#40788204

Answer (score 1):

That's because those imports have imports of their own. For instance if you do:

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
```

And look inside map what it imports, and look another level deeper you get:

```
import { Operator } from '../Operator';
import { Subscriber } from '../Subscriber';
import { Observable } from '../Observable';
import { Observer, PartialObserver } from './Observer';
import { Operator } from './Operator';
import { Subscriber } from './Subscriber';
import { Subscription, AnonymousSubscription, TeardownLogic } from './Subscription';
import { IfObservable } from './observable/IfObservable';
import { ErrorObservable } from './observable/ErrorObservable';
```

... etc, because some of these imports will import other stuff as well, you get that chain of all the files, but still, this is by far not the entire `rxjs` library, and with a good package manager (or by using the angular-cli), the final bundle will only contain what's actually necessary for your app

Comment: ill use something to package eventually and AOT, but asking where to look for what making those calls (i have another project that that doesnt happen in it, ill edit my question

Comment: @BlazzzeIL angular itself also uses the rxjs library extensively. You probably use some angular feature in this project, which you do not in your other project